# Put a list in cell of a table

Tags: list, jasper-reports

I am using *iReport v5.1.0*. I have a table in *Summary* band and I would like to put a list in a cell of that table. I created a sub-dataset and then I tried to connect it with a list. The problem was that i could not see the values in that cell. Is there any other way? The concept is that I have a list of elements that I want to put in a cell of a table.

Comment: What is a type of field\parameter\variable (you want to place in *Summary* band)?

Comment: I place a Table and I want within this table to display a list. There is a component, I use it, but nothing is displayed